# what type of webservice should be created in .NET to work NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, web-services, nsjsonserialization

I'm currently working on `SOAP` Webservice.

I've a requirement in such a way Webservice should support `NSJSONSerialization` method in `iOS` but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Could somebody explain how a `JSON Webservice` can be created please?

Answer (score 0):

This does not depend on `NSJSONSerialization`. Simply format the webservice's answer as required by the JSON standard in [RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc7159.pdf).

Comment: yes i changed the xml format of the SOAP webservice to JASON ,But they are asking a different way, the developers also dont know the exact method name.

Comment: There is nothing special with that. If it is JSON, `NSJSONSerializer` can read and write it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `REST API` in `.NET` so that it will be easily integrate with iPhone app.

Here is the link for the same: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Thank you , I will check it